# I need to understand how &tcb -> context is interpreted by the compiler

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, scheduling

I came across this code for initializing TCB when implementing a non preemptive scheduling..

```
typedef struct TCB_t {
    struct TCB_t     *next;
     struct TCB_t     *prev;
     ucontext_t      context;
} TCB_t;


void init_TCB (TCB_t *tcb, void *function, void *stackP, int stack_size)
{
    memset(tcb, '\0', sizeof(TCB_t));
    getcontext(&tcb->context);              
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_sp = stackP;
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_size = (size_t) stack_size;
    makecontext(&tcb->context, function, 0);  // context is now cooked
}
```

I know that get context in above code takes a pointer to context...but unable to understand how `&tcb->context` is interpreted by compiler...as 
&tcb -> context or &(tcb -> context).....

Comment: It's interpreted as `&(tcp->context)`. `->` has higher precedence than `&`. You can find a list of operator precedences at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.

Comment: @Ulfalizer that looks like an answer

Comment: @immibis: Okay, moving it to answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's interpreted as `&(tcp->context)`. `->` has higher precedence than `&`. You can find a list of operator precedences [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 1):

```
getcontext(&tcb->context);
```

Using clues from the code you've shown, you can deduce that it can *only* be interpreted as `&(tcb->context)`.

`(&tcb)->context` would not make any sense. We know that, in this function, the parameter is declared as `TCB_t *tcb`, which means that `(&tcb)` is of type `TCB_t **`. You can only use the `->` on a pointer-to-struct, not on a double pointer.

Therefore, it must be interpreted as `&(tcb->context)`. With the function prototype for `getcontext`, you could confirm this, by seeing that it takes a `ucontext_t *` parameter, which is what you get when you take the address of (`&`) the `context` member of a `TCB_t`.